# How to show only the first 4 HTML element and hide the rest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu list like this:

[image]

The bold text is the parent, and the thin text is the child.
I want to show only first 4 child when user first see this menu, and to see the rest user can click show more, roughly like this:

[image: modified]

How can I achieve this without changing the HTML element structure by using only CSS, JavaScript, and jQuery to hide the rest of the child and add show more toggle to show/hide the rest of the child?

HTML structure for the child:

```html
<div>
  <div class="nav-item level2"><a href="#" class=" nav-anchor"><span>Body Oil</span></a></div>
  <div class="nav-item level2"><a href="#" class=" nav-anchor"><span>Foot Care</span></a></div>
  <div class="nav-item level2"><a href="#" class=" nav-anchor"><span>Lip Service </span></a></div>
  <div class="nav-item level2"><a href="#" class=" nav-anchor"><span>Massage</span></a></div>
  <div class="nav-item level2"><a href="#" class=" nav-anchor"><span>Sunscreen</span></a></div>
  <div class="nav-item level2"><a href="#" class=" nav-anchor"><span>Eye Cream</span></a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this might help explain why the close votes: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: Here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/c71fxz2e/

Comment: @ChrisG i tried to follow you solution and improve it , so i can toggle to show more and show less, but it seems not working properly https://jsfiddle.net/fon3zsLt/4/

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/so0befy2/

Answer (score 2):

Use `nth-of-type`  like below. And for show more and less use `toggleClass`.

```js
$('#more').on("click", function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  if (text == 'Show-More') {
    $(this).text('Show-Less');
    $('.nav-item').toggleClass("nav-item newClass");
  } else {
    $('.newClass').toggleClass("newClass nav-item");
    $(this).text('Show-More');
  }
});
```

```css
.nav-item:nth-of-type(1n+5) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="nav-item level2"><a href="#" class=" nav-anchor"><span>Body Oil</span></a></div>
  <div class="nav-item level2"><a href="#" class=" nav-anchor"><span>Foot Care</span></a></div>
  <div class="nav-item level2"><a href="#" class=" nav-anchor"><span>Lip Service </span></a></div>
  <div class="nav-item level2"><a href="#" class=" nav-anchor"><span>Massage</span></a></div>
  <div class="nav-item level2"><a href="#" class=" nav-anchor"><span>Sunscreen</span></a></div>
  <div class="nav-item level2"><a href="#" class=" nav-anchor"><span>Eye Cream</span></a></div>
  <span id='more'>Show-More</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, if you look at the question the OP also wants a "Show more" button

Comment: Thanks. I update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is:

1. Add <kbd>Show More</kbd> and <kbd>Show less</kbd> `li`.
2. Bind the event handlers on these `li`s.
3. Show/Hide appropriate `li` depending upon the list size.

Here is the code:

```js
$('.show-more').on('click', function() {
  $('.nav-menu li:gt(3)').show();
  $('.show-less').removeClass('hidden');
  $('.show-more').addClass('hidden');
});

$('.show-less').on('click', function() {
  $('.nav-menu li:gt(3)').hide();
  $('.show-more').removeClass('hidden');
  $('.show-less').addClass('hidden');
});

//Show only four items
if ($('.nav-menu li').length > 4) {
  /*$('.nav-menu li:gt(3)').hide();
  $('.show-more').removeClass('hidden');
  */

  $('.show-less').click();
}
```

```css
.show-more,
.show-less {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 140%;
  background-color: rgba(120, 120, 200, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-menu">
  <li class="nav-menu-item level2"><a href="#" class=" nav-anchor"><span>Body Oil</span></a></li>
  <li class="nav-menu-item level2"><a href="#" class=" nav-anchor"><span>Foot Care</span></a></li>
  <li class="nav-menu-item level2"><a href="#" class=" nav-anchor"><span>Lip Service </span></a></li>
  <li class="nav-menu-item level2"><a href="#" class=" nav-anchor"><span>Massage</span></a></li>
  <li class="nav-menu-item level2"><a href="#" class=" nav-anchor"><span>Sunscreen</span></a></li>
  <li class="nav-menu-item level2"><a href="#" class=" nav-anchor"><span>Eye Cream</span></a></li>
</ul>

<div class='show-more hidden'>SHOW MORE>></div>
<div class='show-less hidden'>
  << SHOW LESS</div>
```